# PS/2 mouse / keyboard interface info and classification

Tags: datasheet, homework, standard, ps2

My hardware interfaces teacher in the university gave a task to find info about **PS/2** interface and fit it into a classification by answering a list of questions. Here's what I've found:

- Which type of connection it uses? **point-to-point** (other variants: *trunk, radial*)
- Which type of Interface it uses? **?** (variants: *parallel, serial, hybrid*)
- Which type of Control is applied between devices? **Centralized** (other variants: *decentralized, partially centralized*)
- Which Operation mode it uses? **half-duplex** (other variants: *simplex, duplex*)
- Which Data exchange mode it uses? **synchronous** (other variants: *async, isochronous*)
- Which Wire types are used to connect devices? **?** (variants: *coaxial, twisted pair, optical fiber, ...*)

But I didn't find some answers. It seems that either the classification is incorrect and there are no answers to some questions or the questions are too simple so I should be able to answer them myself. Can you help me fill the blanks and correct errors? Are the questions asked correctly? Are there even more answer options?

Comment: coaxial is most definitely wrong. I'd say: go find a PS/2 mouse and cut up its cable, but it might be hard to do these days. Are you, by the way, sure this is about the PS/2 mouse/keyboard interface, and not about the hardware architecture of the PS/2 computer? That'd make more sense, because half of the terms apply to networks/buses.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, It's definitely about the interface.

Comment: @MarcusMüller His classification is designed to describe not only to PS/2 and maybe USB, but also, for example, SCSI, VGA, HDMI, DVI, Thunderbolt and others.

Comment: the "type" thing still makes no sense for any of the ones you list, the "Control" thing even less; these are all pure inter-device interconnects, and the options you have are bus architectures. That's like asking what kind of fuel a vehicle takes (e.g. carrots if it's a mule, diesel if it's a car, electricity if it's a golf cart) and having as options "democracy, dictatorship, monarchy". It's the wrong *category* of things.

Comment: @MarcusMüller This is mostly my own vague guesses, because my teacher just told me to "Classify" these interfaces by "Are they this or that?". I don't understand how it would be more correct to call a group of "simplex, duplex, half-duplex", for example.

Comment: I don't understand. Are the **options** "P2P, trunk, radial" coming from your teacher, or are they coming from you? These make no sense here.

Comment: Mostly from teacher and a bit from class mates. I'm just trying to make some sense from them.

Comment: OK, so I'm telling you the third time: these options make no sense. Stop trying to make sense of them.

Comment: @MarcusMüller So, what to do then? How to classify PS/2? Which options to throw away or replace?

Comment: P2P in this context is not `peer-to-peer`, but `point-to-point`

Comment: THat's the thing: **all** the things you list (USB,VGA,HDMI,DVI…) are point-to-point links. None of that is a bus where you could say it's "radial", or where you could have decentralized control. I will stop repeating myself – many of the options you list simply aren't from the right category.

Comment: @MarcusMüller all of these questions make perfect sense if you think about the PS/2 interface vs. other types of interfaces seen on computers for different purposes.  What doesn't make sense is for anyone to try to *answer* the question, because the educational exercise is for the asker to learn enough about the PS/2 interface and the other types of interfaces to figure out which option it is in each category.

Comment: @ChrisStratton :) exactly, I think OP is supposed to understand what kind of systems they're looking at here – and think about what categories to apply. That's why I'm so vehemently trying to think about where these terms apply (and where not).

Comment: @MarcusMüller compare for example the Macintosh II's Apple Desktop Bus keyboard/mouse link for a very different sort of topology.  Compare (coaxial) Ethernet for decentralized control, etc.

Comment: Excellent example; but that's not what OP is trying to do here.

Comment: Sure it is; they've been asked to figure out where PS/2 falls in each dimension of ways that computer/electronic equipment can be interconnected; I was giving examples of things that are very different in several dimensions - specifically ones which illustrate how some of the answer choices you don't seem to think are valid are actually valid distraction answers in a multiple choice assignment, because they do get used elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which type of Interface it uses?

serial, (synchronous, clock and bi-directional data)

> Which Wire types are used to connect devices?

It's just a 4 conductor shielded cable, no twistred pairs or anything fancy.
the shield is there to reduce EMI the wires are +5 ground clock and data. something like 
https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=%203484CSL001-ND%20
keyboards with USB and PS/2 capability (by way of a passive plug adaptor) use a USB compatible cable with twisted pairs instead, this same cable also works with PS/2 - the wire used is not critical a random collection of wires would probably work too.

Comment: About wires. My teacher told me that basically coaxial could be understood just as  a simple insulated conductor. So, coaxial is my choice then?

Comment: coaxial is an insulated conductor with a fitted conductive shield (and usually another layer of insulation). the ps/2 cables conductors do not have individual shields and the shield is not a precise fit.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port

Communication is serial, synchronous and bidirectional.